# Difference between passing simple and reference parameters in Method Overloading and Overriding?

Tags: c#, overriding, overloading

I have three classes:

```
public class A
{
}
public class B
{
    void MethodA(ref A obj) { }

    void MethodB(A obj) { }
}
public class C : B
{
    void MethodA(ref A obj) { }
}
```

**My first question** : Are above methods are overloaded?

**Second question** : Difference between passing simple and refernce type objects as I know classes are reference type.

**Third question** : Is method in class C override method in class B ?

Comment: You keep changing the question. I'd written half an answer, which is now invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1: no; `B.MethodA` and `C.MethodA` are unrelated; the fact that they are implicitly private means it isn't even method-hiding

2: is not a question, but: pass-by-value vs pass-by-reference (the `ref` keyword) is largely orthogonal to value-type vs reference-type (`struct` vs `class`); it is a commonly misunderstood subject, but I can't really clarify without an actual question

3: no; the absence of any of `virtual`, `override` or `abstract` is the biggest clue